# Create and run docker container using Dockerfile and docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker.
I have created a Dockerfile which runs an Angular application inside nginx+docker.

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:12.7-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

### STAGE 2: Run ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/jenkins-test /usr/share/nginx/html
```

to run this i do `docker build -t my-app-multistage-image .` and after that to run container I do `docker run --name my-app-multistage-container -d -p 8888:80 my-app-multistage-image`

It is working fine, now I want to use docker-compose to build and run the container, but no idea how to do that, can anyone please help me.

One code i tried which is obviously not working is

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
```

Thanks

Comment: In what way does that `docker-compose.yml` file not work?  Other than some different names it should be almost identical to the `docker run` command you show.

Comment: It just stops at. Npm install.  Sort of hangs there.

Comment: what's the docker-compose command you're using to build the image?

Comment: Docker-compose up